# How to sort the values of each key of dictionary python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sorting

I have such a dictionary:

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
l = (df.to_dict())
{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '2 4 8', 3: '4 6 7 2'}}
```

and I want to sort the values of each key in descending order which will be:

```
 {0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}
```

Comment: Convert the value to a list of integers. Sort the list. Convert the last back to a string. Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Comment: As an aside, using `pandas` to read a csv into `dict` is rather overkill.  If that's the only part you are using `pandas` for, consider `csv` module which can read `csv` as `OrderedDict`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution using several list/dictionary comprehensions:

```py
d = {0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '2 4 8', 3: '4 6 7 2'}} # original dictionary

# grab the inner dictionary to sort
inner_d = list(d.values())[0]

# reverse order as int
sorted_vals = [sorted(list(map(int, i.split())))[::-1] for i in inner_d.values()]

# convert back to list of joined strings
sorted_vals = [" ".join(a) for a in [[str(j) for j in i] for i in sorted_vals]] 

# rebuild inner dictionary
inner_d = {k:v for k,v in zip(inner_d.keys(), sorted_vals)}

# put back into outer dictionary
d = {0:inner_d}
```

Result: `{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a nested dict comprehension:

```
sep = ' '
result = {
  row: {
    k: sep.join(sorted(v.split(sep), reverse=True))
    for k, v in val.items() 
  } for row, val in l.items()
}
```

Result:

```
{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}
```

As mentioned in my comment, if you only need to read a `csv` as a `dict`, `pandas` is rather overkill.  Look into the [`csv.DictReader` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader) as a viable alternative.

Answer (score 1):

You can use one temporary dictionnary and two loops

```py
for key, value in d.items():
    tmp = {}
    for key1, value1 in value.items():
        tmp[key1] = ' '.join(sorted(value1.split(' '), reverse=True))
    d[key] = tmp
```

output :

```
{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [dict comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to create a new dict, with the values sorted.

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
l = (df.to_dict())

{key:sorted(value) for key, value in l['0'].items()}
```

Since your data is not properly formated, you can turn space delimited strings of numbers into list using "split".

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=None)
l = (df.to_dict())

{key:sorted(value.split(' ')) for key, value in l['0'].items()}
```

If you need to sort the keys as well, you will need  and [ordered dict](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Comment: Did you notice that `l` contains nested dictionaries? And that the values are strings, not lists?

Comment: `sorted("2 4 8")` is `[' ', ' ', '2', '4', '8']`, not `"8 4 2"`

Comment: Missed that part, the answer is now fixed.

Comment: The digits should be re-assembled back into a single string, not left as a list.

Comment: Should they now? That's not quite clear from the question. And if it's needed, it's trivial to do.

Comment: I think it's rather unambiguous that the final values needs to be a single string, as posted in question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dict comprehension for a one line solution, although it will become harder to read. You'll have to split the string into a list, sort it, and then join it back.
You can try something like this:

```
dict = {0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '2 4 8', 3: '4 6 7 2'}}
result = { 0 : { key : ' '.join(sorted(dict[0][key].split(),reverse=True)) for key in dict[0].keys() } }
```

Output:

```
>>> result
{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}
```

Note:

- The solution assumes you only have one element in the outer dictionary, with the key 0. You can loop through the dictionary keys if you have more elements and apply the same logic
- The solution assumes all the element are only digits. If you have numbers of more than 1 digit you'll have to cast the elements to int before sorting, otherwise they will be sorted alphabetically

Comment: The first key of the outer most `dict` is just the row.  There could be `0 .. n` rows.

Comment: Yes, I have mentioned that he can loop over the dict elements and apply the logic.

Comment: The key to writing a good answer is that it's scale-able and solves beyond the surface question.  It's easy to say "you can do x" because *you know* how to do x.  But precisely because OP may not know how is why they ask the question to begin with.  Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Stackoverflow is not meant for solving others homeworks. The solution works perfectly for the provided dict in the question. I don't understand what's your point

Comment: If your goal of posting an answer is just to half answer it, then why bother? Either abstain from an answer and ask for attempt, or *actually answer it*.  On top of that, it's trivial to include the loop in your answer.  I'm just providing suggestion on how to improve your answer.  It's up to you to take it or leave it.

Comment: I'm just telling you that your suggestion doesn't make any sense within this context. Adding a line of code within a for loop has nothing to do with the scalability of the solution. I have explained the logic behind my idea, and provided more than enough details for the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way:

```
a = {0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '2 4 8', 3: '4 6 7 2'}}

for k in a[0].keys():
    a[0].update({k:' '.join(sorted(a[0][k].split(),reverse=True))})

print(a)
```

Output:

```
{0: {0: '1', 1: '6 4', 2: '8 4 2', 3: '7 6 4 2'}}
```